# LIMIT subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the next query, but I get this error:

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
> subquery'

```
SELECT * FROM retail
WHERE session_code IN (
SELECT session_code FROM retail
WHERE utterance REGEXP '...' AND NOT utterance REGEXP '...' 
LIMIT 100
);
```

I found an answer in other thread saying to use JOIN but I can't make it work help! :S

thanks!

Comment: which version of mysql are you using? : run : `select version();`

Comment: When you said you can't make it work using `JOIN` does that mean you have tried with `JOIN` but the result is not you've expected or you haven't managed to work out how to turn the query into `JOIN` yet?

Answer (score 0):

one way is :

```
SELECT distinct r.* FROM retail r
join session_code sc
 on sc.session_code = r.session_code
 and utterance REGEXP '...' 
 and NOT utterance REGEXP '...' 
limit 100;
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: but session_code is not a table but a column, so i get an error because the table session_code does not exists

Comment: I assumed you have another table that keeps sessions code @claudiasilva